# SQLExpress database file auto-creation error - after deploying to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Was going about with our usual deployment of code (ASP.NET MVC solution) to Azure to a test instance as an App service. The solution works on local machine, but started throwing this exception in Azure.

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"*

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

*** SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: ***

Unfortunately this seems to be happening even for other environments now. I haven't changed anything there except redeploying. This has nothing to do with connectionString, have triple checked it on the server itself. Basically the solution as it is works, and have been working for all this while, but since last week all new deployments are failing with this error. Even re-deploying the old code seems to fail. I am afraid to try it on any new environments.

No recent changes were made to web.config, all that was updated was some UI components. In any case, even the older code that is running on other environments are failing. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Unless you're actually pointing to Azure SQL Database with your connection string, you're not getting Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 2):

SQLExpress only exists within Visual Studio. On something like Azure, you need a connection string that points to a real instance of a SQL Server database.